# PHP header content type and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, header, http-headers, content-type

I've put some external application on a phpBB3 forum (in its common.php file) and since the two applications use different kind of encoding, the phpBB started outputing headers sent message.I've removed the external application and the headers sent message is still there.

How can I fix it, I've issued this before, I add header() (with some other encoding) and after removing it or chaning it to UTF-8, it still stays the old one.

Comment: Reading between the lines here, I suspect what you have done is converted `common.php` to UTF-8 with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). The BOM is outside the `<?php ?>` tags and is being output directly, and this is causing the headers to be sent, so you can no longer modify them and see the warning. You should open `common.php` and convert it to a uni-byte codepage or UTF-8 without BOM.